# Slickgrid: Get reference to column changed by columnPicker

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using the slickgrid columnPicker to show/hide a specific column

I tried using

```js
columnpicker.onColumnsChanged.subscribe((e, args) => {
   console.log("hello world");
})
```

but `args` only gives me all visible columns.

I need to trigger an event when a specific column is being shown.

Is it possible to get a reference to the specific column that was shown/hidden using the columnPicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added the column id 3 years ago, so I can only assume that you are either on a version that is too old OR you're not using the [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) fork which is the most active one.

The latest code is providing the following

```js
onColumnsChanged.notify({ columnId: columnId, showing: isChecked, allColumns: columns, columns: visibleColumns, grid: _grid });
```

so you should be able to subscribe to the event and get the `columnId`

```js
columnpicker.onColumnsChanged.subscribe((e, args) => {
   console.log("column id changed", args.columnId);
})
```

the same is true for the Grid Menu as well

```js
gridMenu.onColumnsChanged.subscribe((e, args) => {
   console.log("column id changed", args.columnId);
})
```

You can see this [PR](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/561) in which I added the `columnId` to the event. This is available since [v2.4.32](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2432-2020-12-02) of [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) fork

Comment: Ah you're right. I'm on version 2.3. Thanks!